# Detect height on position:relative div with position:absolute children

Tags: html, css

I've got a div that contains a photo tiling style I've been working on. The parent div over all the photos is `position:relative` while the divs inside holding the photos are `position:absolute`

I have to use 'position:absolute` for the children to get the layout I want but the problem arises when the parent div (either .daddy or .floatcont) doesn't register with a height and appears empty.

How can I make the parent register a height so I can put content below it on the page?

Code here: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/iBgsp

```
.floatcont {
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
}

.floatpic {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned elements are removed from the flow, thus ignored by other elements. So you can't set the parents height according to an absolutely positioned element.

In your case, I have come up with one solution. Update your .sixth class like below.

```
.floatpic.sixth {
  top: 270vh;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
  position:relative;
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ldHoF)